# Pulling out a value from a dictionary nested in a list nested in another dictionary... nested in another dictionary

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to use Google CSE to do some scraping for a project. This is pretty much my first time scraping. I took a python class a couple of quarters ago at school and scraping was slated to be one of our last topics but we never really got to it. Anyway...

**Here's what I'm trying to do:**

Use Google CSE to pull google news results for "bird watching" and "bird feeding". From the results of the query I want to pull the article title, the article link, and the date it was published. Then I want to write that all to a csv.

**Here's what I've got down so far** (with lots of help from https://gist.github.com/nikhilkumarsingh/5bce182ed57ae73f6cbde52fe846991b , if anyone else is looking for an intro to CSE, this one is great!!):

Getting the query results, using a for loop to return the title and the link. For now I'm just printing it out to make sure I'm getting the results. I'll write to csv later. My query results object is a dictionary named "result", which looks like this (I apologize for the sheer amount of code I'm about to post but my issue pertains to nesting so I figured this is the clearest way to explain):

```
    {'kind': 'customsearch#search', 'url': {'type': 'application/json',
 'template': 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=
{searchTerms}&num={count?}&start={startIndex?}&lr={language?}&safe=
{safe?}&cx={cx?}&sort={sort?}&filter={filter?}&gl={gl?}&cr=
{cr?}&googlehost={googleHost?}&c2coff={disableCnTwTranslation?}&hq=
{hq?}&hl={hl?}&siteSearch={siteSearch?}&siteSearchFilter=
{siteSearchFilter?}&exactTerms={exactTerms?}&excludeTerms=
{excludeTerms?}&linkSite={linkSite?}&orTerms={orTerms?}&relatedSite=
{relatedSite?}&dateRestrict={dateRestrict?}&lowRange=
{lowRange?}&highRange={highRange?}&searchType={searchType}&fileType=
{fileType?}&rights={rights?}&imgSize={imgSize?}&imgType=
{imgType?}&imgColorType={imgColorType?}&imgDominantColor=
{imgDominantColor?}&alt=json'}, 'queries': {'request': [{'title': 'Google 
Custom Search - bird watching', 'totalResults': '104000', 'searchTerms': 
'bird watching', 'count': 10, 'startIndex': 1, 'inputEncoding': 'utf8', 
'outputEncoding': 'utf8', 'safe': 'off', 'cx': 
'017465438656188383295:ul7lxhkonwq'}], 'nextPage': [{'title': 'Google 
Custom Search - bird watching', 'totalResults': '104000', 'searchTerms': 
'bird watching', 'count': 10, 'startIndex': 11, 'inputEncoding': 'utf8',
 'outputEncoding': 'utf8', 'safe': 'off', 'cx': 
'017465438656188383295:ul7lxhkonwq'}]}, 'context': {'title': 'google 
news'}, 'searchInformation': {'searchTime': 0.491713, 
'formattedSearchTime': '0.49', 'totalResults': '104000', 'formattedTotalResults': '104,000'}, 'items': [{'kind': 
'customsearch#result', 'title': 'Amy Cooper: White woman who called police 
on a black man in ...', 'htmlTitle': 'Amy Cooper: White woman who called 
police on a black man in ...', 'link': 
'https://news.google.com/articles/CAIiEDCQPCzyU2erjQLyLr_nLqUqGQgEKhAIACoH
CAowocv1CjCSptoCMPrTpgU?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen', 'displayLink': 
'news.google.com', 'snippet': 'May 26, 2020 ... White woman who called 
police on a black man bird-watching in Central Park \nhas been fired. By 
Amir Vera and Laura Ly, CNN. Updated 4:21\xa0...', 'htmlSnippet': 'May 26, 
2020 <b>...</b> White woman who called police on a black man <b>bird</b>-
<b>watching</b> in Central Park <br>\nhas been fired. By Amir Vera and 
Laura Ly, CNN. Updated 4:21&nbsp;...', 'formattedUrl': 
'https://news.google.com/.../CAIiEDCQPCzyU2erjQLyLr_ 
nLqUqGQgEKhAIACoHCAowocv1CjCSptoCMPrTpgU?...', 'htmlFormattedUrl': 
'https://news.google.com/.../CAIiEDCQPCzyU2erjQLyLr_ 
nLqUqGQgEKhAIACoHCAowocv1CjCSptoCMPrTpgU?...', 'pagemap': {'thumbnail': 
[{'src': 'https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/200526102231-02-central-
park-video-dog-video-african-american-trnd-screengrab-super-tease.jpg'}],
 'metatags': [{'template-top': 'us,news,art-vid-vls-col,col-top-news', 
'og:image': 'https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/200526102231-02-
central-park-video-dog-video-african-american-trnd-screengrab-super-
tease.jpg', 'twitter:card': 'summary_large_image', 'og:image:width': 
'1100', 'theme-color': '#000000', 'og:site_name': 'CNN', 'section': 'us', 
'vr:canonical': 'https://www.cnn.com/2020/05/26/us/central-park-video-dog-
video-african-american-trnd/index.html', 'article:content-tier': 'free', 
'og:description': 'The white woman who called police on a black man in 
Central Park during an encounter involving her unleashed dog has been 
fired from her job, her employer said Tuesday.', 'twitter:image': 
'https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/200526102231-02-central-park-
video-dog-video-african-american-trnd-screengrab-super-tease.jpg', 'og:pubdate': '2020-05-26T06:19:40Z', 'lastmod': '2020-05-26T20:21:18Z', 'pubdate': '2020-05-26T06:19:40Z', 'twitter:title': 'White woman who called police on a black man bird-watching in Central Park has been fired', 'og:type': 'article', 'thumbnail': 'https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/200526102231-02-central-park-video-dog-video-african-american-trnd-screengrab-super-tease.jpg', 
'author': 'Amir Vera and Laura Ly, CNN', 'og:title': 'White woman who 
called police on a black man bird-watching in Central Park has been 
fired', 'og:image:height': '619', 'fb:pages': '5550296508,18793419640', 
'referrer': 'unsafe-url', 'fb:app_id': '80401312489', 'viewport': 
'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0', 
'twitter:description': 'The white woman who called police on a black man 
in Central Park during an encounter involving her unleashed dog has been 
fired from her job, her employer said Tuesday.', 'og:url': 
'https://www.cnn.com/2020/05/26/us/central-park-video-dog-video-african-
american-trnd/index.html', 'article:opinion': 'false'}], 'cse_image': 
[{'src': 'https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/200526102231-02-central-
park-video-dog-video-african-american-trnd-screengrab-super-tease.jpg', 
'width': '299', 'type': '1', 'height': '168'}], 'newsarticle': [{'image': 
'https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/200526102231-02-central-park-
video-dog-video-african-american-trnd-screengrab-super-tease.jpg', 
'keywords': 'us, Amy Cooper: White woman who called police on a black man 
in Central Park has been fired - CNN', 'author': 'Amir Vera and Laura Ly, 
CNN', 'ispartof': 'news', 'description': 'The white woman who called 
police on a black man in Central Park during an encounter involving her 
unleashed dog has been fired from her job, her employer said Tuesday.', 
'datecreated': '2020-05-26T06:19:40Z', 'url': 
'https://www.cnn.com/2020/05/26/us/central-park-video-dog-video-african-
american-trnd/index.html', 'articlebody': '(CNN)The white woman who called
 police on a black man in Central Park during an encounter involving her 
unleashed dog has been fired from her job, her employer said 
Tuesday."Following our internal...', 'datemodified': '2020-05-
26T20:21:18Z', 'articlesection': 'us', 'alternativeheadline': 'White woman who called police on a black man bird-watching in Central Park has been 
fired', 'headline': 'Amy Cooper: White woman who called police on a black 
man in Central Park has been fired - CNN', 'datepublished': '2020-05-
26T06:19:40Z', 'thumbnailurl': 
'https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/200526102231-02-central-park-
video-dog-video-african-american-trnd-screengrab-super-tease.jpg'}]}}
```

My code for the pulling out the link and title looks like this:

```
for item in result['items']:
    print(item['title'], item['link'])
```

**Here's what I'm stuck on:**

The key for the date the article was published, 'pubdate' is nested within many dictionaries and lists. I'm having a very hard time pulling it out in a loop. Nesting, whether it's in the form of loops or data structure is probably my biggest weakness in coding.

The key that contains all the info I'm interested in is 'items', which has a value that is a list of dictionaries:

```
'items': [{'kind': 'customsearch#result', 'title': 'Amy Cooper: White 
woman who called police on a black man in ...', 'htmlTitle': 'Amy Cooper: 
White woman who called police on a black man in ...', 'link': 
'https://news.google.com/articles/CAIiEDCQPCzyU2erjQLyLr_nLqUqGQgEKhAIACoH
CAowocv1CjCSptoCMPrTpgU?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen', 'displayLink': 
'news.google.com', 'snippet': 'May 26, 2020 ... White woman who called 
police on a black man bird-watching in Central Park \nhas been fired. By 
Amir Vera and Laura Ly, CNN. Updated 4:21\xa0...', 'htmlSnippet': 'May 26,
 2020 <b>...</b> White woman who called police on a black man <b>bird</b>-
<b>watching</b> in Central Park <br>\nhas been fired. By Amir Vera and 
Laura Ly, CNN. Updated 4:21&nbsp;...', 'formattedUrl': 
'https://news.google.com/.../CAIiEDCQPCzyU2erjQLyLr_ 
nLqUqGQgEKhAIACoHCAowocv1CjCSptoCMPrTpgU?...', 'htmlFormattedUrl': 
'https://news.google.com/.../CAIiEDCQPCzyU2erjQLyLr_ 
nLqUqGQgEKhAIACoHCAowocv1CjCSptoCMPrTpgU?...', 'pagemap': {'thumbnail': 
[{'src': 'https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/200526102231-02-central-
park-video-dog-video-african-american-trnd-screengrab-super-tease.jpg'}], 
'metatags': [{'template-top': 'us,news,art-vid-vls-col,col-top-news', 
'og:image': 'https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/200526102231-02-
central-park-video-dog-video-african-american-trnd-screengrab-super-
tease.jpg', 'twitter:card': 'summary_large_image', 'og:image:width': 
'1100', 'theme-color': '#000000', 'og:site_name': 'CNN', 'section': 'us', 
'vr:canonical': 'https://www.cnn.com/2020/05/26/us/central-park-video-dog-
video-african-american-trnd/index.html', 'article:content-tier': 'free', 
'og:description': 'The white woman who called police on a black man in 
Central Park during an encounter involving her unleashed dog has been
 fired from her job, her employer said Tuesday.', 'twitter:image': 
'https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/200526102231-02-central-park-
video-dog-video-african-american-trnd-screengrab-super-tease.jpg', 
'og:pubdate': '2020-05-26T06:19:40Z', 'lastmod': '2020-05-26T20:21:18Z', 
'pubdate': '2020-05-26T06:19:40Z', 'twitter:title': 'White woman who 
called police on a black man bird-watching in Central Park has been 
fired', 'og:type': 'article', 'thumbnail': 
'https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/200526102231-02-central-park-
video-dog-video-african-american-trnd-screengrab-super-tease.jpg', 
'author': 'Amir Vera and Laura Ly, CNN', 'og:title': 'White woman who 
called police on a black man bird-watching in Central Park has been 
fired', 'og:image:height': '619', 'fb:pages': '5550296508,18793419640', 
'referrer': 'unsafe-url', 'fb:app_id': '80401312489', 'viewport': 
'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0', 
'twitter:description': 'The white woman who called police on a black man 
in Central Park during an encounter involving her unleashed dog has been 
fired from her job, her employer said Tuesday.', 'og:url': 
'https://www.cnn.com/2020/05/26/us/central-park-video-dog-video-african-
american-trnd/index.html', 'article:opinion': 'false'}]
```

within this first dictionary in the list aka = result['items'][0] , we have key 'pagemap', whose value is another dictionary in which we have the key 'metatags' whose value is a list of dictionaries. The first index of this list contains a dictionary with the key whose value I'm looking for 'pubdate' (I put a couple spaces in the code block so you can easily find this value):

```
'metatags': [{'template-top': 'us,news,art-vid-vls-col,col-top-news', 
'og:image': 'https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/200526102231-02-
central-park-video-dog-video-african-american-trnd-screengrab-super-
tease.jpg', 'twitter:card': 'summary_large_image', 'og:image:width': 
'1100', 'theme-color': '#000000', 'og:site_name': 'CNN', 'section': 'us',
 'vr:canonical': 'https://www.cnn.com/2020/05/26/us/central-park-video-
dog-video-african-american-trnd/index.html', 'article:content-tier': 
'free', 'og:description': 'The white woman who called police on a black 
man in Central Park during an encounter involving her unleashed dog has 
been fired from her job, her employer said Tuesday.', 'twitter:image':
 'https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/200526102231-02-central-park-
video-dog-video-african-american-trnd-screengrab-super-tease.jpg', 
'og:pubdate': '2020-05-26T06:19:40Z', 'lastmod': '2020-05-26T20:21:18Z',



'pubdate': '2020-05-26T06:19:40Z', 'twitter:title': 'White woman who 
called police on a black man bird-watching in Central Park has been 
fired', 'og:type': 'article', 'thumbnail': 
'https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/200526102231-02-central-park-
video-dog-video-african-american-trnd-screengrab-super-tease.jpg', 
'author': 'Amir Vera and Laura Ly, CNN', 'og:title': 'White woman who 
called police on a black man bird-watching in Central Park has been 
fired', 'og:image:height': '619', 'fb:pages': '5550296508,18793419640', 
'referrer': 'unsafe-url', 'fb:app_id': '80401312489', 'viewport': 
'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0', 
'twitter:description': 'The white woman who called police on a black man 
in Central Park during an encounter involving her unleashed dog has been 
fired from her job, her employer said Tuesday.', 'og:url': 
'https://www.cnn.com/2020/05/26/us/central-park-video-dog-video-african-
american-trnd/index.html', 'article:opinion': 'false'}]
```

Hopefully you've been able to follow with me through this rather gnarly nest structure...

**So ideally what I am looking for is a loop that would give me back :**

```
Amy Cooper: White woman who called police on a black man in ... https://news.google.com/articles/CAIiEDCQPCzyU2erjQLyLr_nLqUqGQgEKhAIACoHCAowocv1CjCSptoCMPrTpgU?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen
2020-05-26T06:19:40Z
```

and so on for the next story in my query results.

The closest I've gotten is:

```
for item in result['items']:
        print(item['title'], item['link'])
        for date in result['items'][0]['pagemap']['metatags']:
            print (date['pubdate'])
```

this is close but only gives back the date for the first story, even as the loop moves on to the next story:

```
Amy Cooper: White woman who called police on a black man in ... https://news.google.com/articles/CAIiEDCQPCzyU2erjQLyLr_nLqUqGQgEKhAIACoHCAowocv1CjCSptoCMPrTpgU?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen
2020-05-26T06:19:40Z
Christian Cooper shouldn't need a Harvard degree to survive birding ... https://news.google.com/articles/CAIiEOCKmxd9S5s5cwM5xs0AivoqGAgEKg8IACoHCAowjtSUCjC30XQwzqe5AQ?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen
2020-05-26T06:19:40Z
People called police on this black birdwatcher so many times that he ... https://news.google.com/articles/CAIiEOkNNX95htD_KKDYihI5JcoqGAgEKg8IACoHCAowjtSUCjC30XQwzqe5AQ?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen
2020-05-26T06:19:40Z
A black man bird-watching in Central Park asked a white woman to ... https://news.google.com/articles/CAIiENZfU5G5gfmzo2CysHOaY0sqFQgEKg0IACoGCAowuLUIMNFnMLnhAg?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen
2020-05-26T06:19:40Z
What's a Tough Call in Bird Watching? Identifying a Gull - WSJ https://news.google.com/articles/CAIiEMKd4gQ1olRNd5T2Ndlpiu8qGAgEKg8IACoHCAow1tzJATDnyxUwuK20AQ
2020-05-26T06:19:40Z
Any advice, tips, help, or words of nested for loop wisdom would be greatly appreciated!!!!
```

Comment: In your second for loop, you are constantly refering to `result['items']`. I believe you meant `item['items']`.

Answer (score 1):

You are every time accesing to first cell of array in `result['items'][0]`. Working code:

```
for item in result['items']:
    print(item['title'], item['link'])
    for date in item['pagemap']['metatags']:
        print(date.get('pubdate', 'Pubdate is not specified'))
```

Comment: Hi Anton! Thank you for your help. I think this is definitely getting me on the right track but with this code gives a key error on the inner loop on the second iteration...

Comment: Hi! It runs well for example in question. Can you add full dict to your question?

Comment: It actually goes over the word count limit when I post the whole thing here. I just posted it on GitHub: https://gist.github.com/gwestle1/278a9418f61af55339a65512020bd655

Comment: It just don't have publication date specified. I updated my answer with code that avoids error